# Elasticsearch DSL bool query for filtration

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an Elasticsearch DSL query as below

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "api": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "api": "B"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "api": "C"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand, this is something like

match if (api = A or api = B or api = C)

I want to add another condition checking a different field in the third check.

E.g match if (api = A or api = B or (api = C and another_field = D ) ) Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`bool/must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "api": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "api": "B"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "api": "C"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "another_field": "D"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```